# Performance tuning in Cognos Report Studio

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi, cognos-10

Working in `Cognos Report Studio 10.2.1`. I have two query items. First query item is the base table which results in some million records. Second query item is coming from a different table. I need to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the first query item with other. In the third query item post the join, I am filtering on a date column which is in format`YYYYMM` to give me records falling under `201406 i.e the current Month and Year`. This is the common column in both the table apart from `AcctNo` which is used to join both the tables.  
 The problem is, when I try to view `Tabular data`the report takes forever to run. After waiting patiently for 30 mins, I just have to cancel the report. When I add the same filter criteria to the 1st query item on the date column and then view the third query item, it gives me the output. But in the long run, I have to join multiple tables with this base table and in one of the table the filter criteria needs to give output for two months. 
 I am converting a `SAS code to Cognos`, In SAS code, there is no filter on the base table and even then the join query takes few seconds to run. 
My question is: Is there any way to improve the performance of the query so that it runs and more importantly runs in less time? 
 Pl note: Modelling my query in FM is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this resolved myself after many trial and errors.

What I did is created a copy of 1st Query item, and filtered 1st query item with current month and year and the for the copy of 1st query item added a filter for two months. That way I was able to run my query and get the desired results.
Though this is a rare case scenario, hope it helps someone else.